# Stretching SVGs in TailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, svg, tailwind-css

I'm currently working on a landing page with TailwindCSS, and I'd like to add a decorative item under my headlines. I've created an SVG and used the `after` pseudo-element to position it under the item I want. Here's an example:

```
<span after:h-5 after:bg-[url('../public/svg/underline-large.svg')] after:bg-no-repeat />
```

However, the issue here is that I end up having to bring in longer and shorter SVGs for different headlines. Ideally I would be able to use one SVG and somehow stretch it to match the width of the title. Any idea of how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need some more (after:) options and a **relative** class, but the most important part to add this  `preserveAspectRatio="none"` attribute to the svg.

###### HTML

```html
<h1
  class="text-2xl
  relative 
  after:content-['']
  after:h-[1rem]
  after:w-full
  after:absolute
  after:bottom-[-1.2rem]
  after:left-[0]
  after:bg-[url('./underline.svg')]
  after:bg-no-repeat"
>
  Short Title
</h1>
```

###### SVG

```html
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 63 8" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M5.47663 1.41505C21.2121 3.69552 49.2623 6.09008 61.691 1.41505C52.455 5.86203 35.6249 8.49799 1.14368 4.49373" stroke="#2AADD6" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</svg>
```

[image: Edit dazziling-code]